# Неправильное копирование текста одного файла в другой

Tags: c, файлы

После прочитанных символов из входного файла, в буфер также записываются непонятные символы (при выводе в консоль то же самое). Я уже писал такого рода программы, но никогда такого не было. Может я где-то что-то упустил...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define OUTPUT_MODE 0700

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int f_in, f_out, rd, wr;

    if(argc != 3) exit(1);

    f_in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    f_out = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);
    while(1)
    {
        rd = read(f_in, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if(rd <= 0) break;
        wr = write(f_out, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if(wr <= 0) exit(2);
    }
    close(f_out);
    close(f_in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Когда вы делаете read, он может прочитать данных меньше чем BUF_SIZE. А когда вы делаете write, вы всегда записываете ровно BUF_SIZE данных — логично, что если read не заполнил конец буфера, то в конце буфера оказывается мусор, который вы и записываете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
do
{
    rd = read(f_in, buf, BUF_SIZE);
    wr = write(f_out, buf, rd);
} while(rd == BUF_SIZE);
```

Comment: Хочется поставить и + и - ))))  (- за отсутствие обработки errno) xD

Comment: ТОЧНО! `wr = write(f_out, buf, rd);` Спасибо большое!

Comment: И если у нас пришёл сигнал... попробуйте ещё раз. @Maggot JFYI (комментарий адресован автору ответа)